# How to drag and drop one div onto another in Cypress test using cypress-drag-drop package?

Tags: drag-and-drop, cypress

I am trying to write a Cypress test that drags & drops column A onto column B on this webpage - https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop

I installed the `@4tw/cypress-drag-drop` package & added the following to my `support/commands.js`:
require("@4tw/cypress-drag-drop");

Here is my Cypress code:

```
cy.get("#column-a").drag("#column-b", { force: true });
```

The test passes, but the columns aren't behaving the same way visually as it does when I manually drag column A onto column B.

Instead, this is what appears on the browser in Cypress Explorer:

As you can see, column A is greyed out, as if it were dragged, but not dropped

[image]

Can someone please point out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, the library does not support the correct events for this page.

But you can do it using Cypress commands.

These are the events used on the page

```js
col.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart, false);
col.addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnter, false);
col.addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver, false);
col.addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragLeave, false);
col.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop, false);
col.addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd, false);
```

This is the test that passes

```js
// check initial order
cy.get('div.column')
  .then($cols => [...$cols].map(col => col.innerText.trim()))
  .should('deep.eq', ['A', 'B'])

const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer;

cy.get("#column-a")
  .trigger('dragstart', {dataTransfer})
cy.get("#column-b")
  .trigger('dragenter')
  .trigger('dragover', {dataTransfer})
  .trigger('drop', {dataTransfer})
cy.get("#column-a")
  .trigger('dragend')

// check new order
cy.get('div.column')
  .then($cols => [...$cols].map(col => col.innerText.trim()))
  .should('deep.eq', ['B', 'A'])

// check drag opacity reverted back
cy.get("#column-a").should('have.css', 'opacity', '1')
cy.get("#column-b").should('have.css', 'opacity', '1')
```